# "Find a file" search function does not work in my SharePoint document library

Tags: search, sharepoint, document-library, sharepointadmin, sharepoint-documents

I transferred a bunch of files to a newly created `SharePoint` site. I have full access to the site but every time I search for a file it always returns the error message:

> Your search returned no results. 
>   Some files might be hidden. Include these in your search.

It never finds anything even when the file is in fact in the directory. I looked all over the internet and tried tweaking settings according to people's suggestions but I can't seem to fix it.

Can anyone please help me out?

I created the team site from scratch and I would think the search function is "activated" by default.

Answer (score 1):

have you configured SharePoint Search service? if you have done, then check Crawl Logs 
1.In Central Administration, in the Quick Launch, click Application Management.

2.On the Application Management page, under Service Applications, click Manage service applications.

3.On the Service Applications page, in the list of service applications, click the Search service application that you want.

4.On the Search Administration page, in the Quick Launch, under Crawling, click Crawl Log.

5.On the Crawl Log – Content Source page, click the view that you want.